# Proving Mean Value Theorem for Harmonic functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was reading a proof of the mean value theorem of a harmonic function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and couldn't understand this step.

$\frac{1}{n\alpha (n)r^{n-1}}\int_{\delta B(x,r)}f(y)dS(y)=\frac{1}{n\alpha (n)}\int_{\delta B(0,1)}f(x+rz)dS(z)$

Can anyone explain what happened to the $r^{n-1}$ term?
Thanks.

Also what exactly is $z$ in the transform $y\to x+rz$

Comment: Note that $r$ is the radius of the ball $B(x,r)$ centered at $x$. The transformation looks like a shift and a rescaling by $r$. I can't provide the rigorous argument for you, but notice that the transformation amounts to bringing out a factor of $r^{n-1}$ from the $dS(z)$ term since the volume of the ball scales like $r^n$ but the surface area scales like $r^{n-1}$.

Comment: It's a linear change of variables. Look at what happened to the region of integration.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I know the region shifted and expanded/contracted. I am having a hard time realizing what $dS(z)$ is